# elderly mom transfrred bitcoin out of coinbase but doesn't know where it went ... have identifiers and hash stuff

Tags: hash, coinbase.com, lost-bitcoins

My mom is and she transferred bitcoin out of her coinbase account which we finally regained access.

She does not know where she transferred it to, i.e., a wallet, or other account?

We have the transaction data from Coinbase showing the identifiers and hash ids but can't figure out how to trace where it went. We looked a a few of those hashes / identifiers by copying and pasting them into the search at bitcoin.com and they returned information reporting those transactions as occurring, stating the value, the charge for the transaction, and that that section of the "block" now has no value.

Any way to find where the lost bitcoin went?

Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 1):

A transaction ID or bitcoin address alone will give you no clues as to what sort of wallet created the address that the bitcoin was sent to.

You will need to work with you mom to remember where the coins were sent. Try searching her digital devices for wallet applications, her email for wallet backups or exchange/wallet service registration emails, her physical belongings for wallet backups (mnemonic seed phrases, or perhaps a paper wallet of some sort), or anywhere else you might be able to find a clue.

Without any other information, I'm not sure anyone here can be of much further help.